# Laravel 5.3 can not login but artisan tinker does

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have a production Laravel app working but I cloned it to my laptop (macos 10.13 brew php native apache macos server 5) and it is unable to login. It just redirects to the login page again. I have debugbar but it does not show nothing unusual.
I made the regular permissions change `sudo find  ~/myapp -type d -exec chmod -v 755 {} \;` and `sudo find  ~/myapp -type f -exec chmod -v 644 {} \;` but no change. Also i checked for the correct file structure in storage and seems fine.
Based on a tinker error:

```
>>> $user = EMMA5\User::find(913)
=> EMMA5\User {#916
     id: 913,
     username: "osito",
     name: "Ozzy",
     last_name: "Campuzano",
     email: "osito@ardillanet.com",
     deleted_at: null,
     created_at: "2016-12-21 14:37:07",
     updated_at: "2017-08-26 02:31:06",
     board_id: 28,
     center_id: 1803,
     completion_year: 2016,
     birth: null,
     gender: null,
     identifier: null,
   }
>>> Auth::login($user)
PHP Warning:  unlink(~/myapp/storage/framework/sessions/RVoouWblwZWdYnFjGkVsPhwl0s8Q9g4ARfQPRHXi): No such file or directory in ~/myapp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php on line 172
=> null
```

I switched to database session so in tinker a got this:

```
>>> $user = EMMA5\User::find(913)
=> EMMA5\User {#916
     id: 913,
     username: "osito",
     name: "Ozzy",
     last_name: "Campuzano",
     email: "osito@ardillanet.com",
     deleted_at: null,
     created_at: "2016-12-21 14:37:07",
     updated_at: "2017-08-26 02:31:06",
     board_id: 28,
     center_id: 1803,
     completion_year: 2016,
     birth: null,
     gender: null,
     identifier: null,
   }
>>> Auth::login($user)
=> null
```

But on the browser I get the same behaviour.
I am very confused because on my desktop and my production server i got everything working fine.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If all settings are set correctly, try php artisan cache:clear and view:clear.

And make sure APP_KEY in your .env is the same as the one in your production server. ([see](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/283/generating-a-new-application-key) what happens if it's different)

Comment: Yes both are the same and did the cache clear via artisan and manually deleted the views and the cache. But I noticed that the views are created with my user and not _www as expected. Thanks.